# Javascript string concatenation with a function behaves strange

Tags: javascript, string, function, concatenation

I am trying to concate something like `"string"+function(){return "string"}` in `document.write()` in javascript.

For example:

```
document.write("I don't know "+function(){if(true){return "why does it concat?"}});
```

And it prints something like this bellow (see it running in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sadaf2605/3AuLD/):

```
I don't know function (){if(true){return "why does it concat?"}}
```

I know I have written something very very silly, I need a function to make it done but still why should it print something like this? I am curious about that!

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  You're explicitly telling it to convert a function to a string.  You're not *calling* the function, if that's what you want to happen.  Add `()` after the function body.

Comment: "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking why it printed what it did, it's because your function was converted to a string (via its `toString` method), since you were trying to concatenate a string and a function object. When a function is converted to a string, its source code is returned (unless it's a native function).

This happens according to the language specification ([15.3.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2)):

> **Function.prototype.toString ( )**
>
> An implementation-dependent representation of the function is
>   returned. This representation has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration.
>   Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line
>   terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is
>   implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is:

```
document.write("I don't know "+ (function(){if(true){return "why does it concat?"}})());
                                ^_______                                             ^_____
```

You are not executing the function. You can create a immediate function to execute. Also since you have one of the operands a string and you are using `+` operator on them, your function expression is automatically casted to string as well.

When you just use `function(){if(true){return "why does it concat?"}}` it is just a function reference not the result, so you see the result that way. You need to execute the function and get the return value instead.

Comment: actually I know that, but why should it behave like that? :/

Comment: You don't really need those outer parentheses, since the parser already knows it's looking at an expression and not a function declaration statement. Can't hurt of course.

Comment: @sadaf2605 it would help a lot if you would explain what you expected it to do instead.

Comment: @Pointy yeah true. it is not need.. But i am used to use it.. :)

Comment: @sadaf2605 see the second para.